# In laravel project multi authentication problem

Tags: php, laravel

in my projects 3 roles (user,employer,admin)
if i log in with user there is no problem.
but login with employer i have a problem.it is logged in as a guest and employer.

i had restrict employer to access login page after successful login. but in my case both employer and guest are in my session.

please give solution i need to forget guest after successful login.

```php
Class LoginController
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('employer.auth.login');
    }


    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('employer');
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed the `laravel-blade` tag since it's unrelated

Comment: lets see your auth.php

Comment: 'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'user',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
'guards' => [
        'user' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
         
         'employer' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'employers',
        ],
         

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

Comment: 'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\model\user\User::class,
        ],

         'employers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\model\employer\employer::class,
        ],

Comment: show me your login controller

Comment: public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);if($this->guard()->validate($this->credentials($request)))
       {
        $user=$this->guard()->getLastAttempted();
        if($user->active && $this->attemptLogin($request))
          {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
          }
           else
          {
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
        $user->code=User::otp($user->phone);

Comment: if($user->save())
            {
           session()->put('phonestore', $request->phone);
           return redirect('employer/otpverify');
            }
        
          }
       } $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }

Comment: Please help to resolve my issue